# simplest recommended outgoing email in perl?

Tags: perl, email

I would like to set up a basic email sender.  this is to validate the email of users on my website and give them a token to click on.  the server is not set up for email.  it is a vanilla ubuntu box, and I really don't want to run a mail server, partly because I don't want another open port to worry about.  I also would like the programming to be simple and avoid spam filters.

first, I tried Gmail.

```
use Net::SMTP::TLS;
my $mailer = new Net::SMTP::TLS(  'smtp.gmail.com',
                  Hello   => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                  Port    => 587,
                  User    => $me2,
                  Password=> $pw);
```

but I got complaints about 'Net::SMTP::TLS for Gmail => invalid SSL_version'.

then I tried Email::Send::Gmail.

```
my $email_address = $me;

($me =~ /^[\w\-_\.]+\@[\w\-_\.]+$/) or die "$email_address is invalid";

use Email::Send;
use Email::Send::Gmail;
use Email::Simple::Creator;

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
                  header => [
                         From    => $me,
                         To      => $me,
                         Subject => 'Testing',
                        ],
                  body => 'Testing email sending with perl.',
                 );

my $sender = Email::Send->new(
                  {   mailer      => 'Gmail',
                  mailer_args => [
                          username => $me2,
                          password => $pw,
                         ]
                  }
                 );
eval { $sender->send($email) };
die "Error sending email: $@" if $@;
```

this one complained that Return::Value is deprecated.  then, it failed---possibly because I have two-factor authentication on my gmail account.  this is getting too complex for what I wanted.

for this simple a task, what is the recommended simplest approach?

Comment: Why not create a second GMail account for just this purpose and tuern off two-factor authentication for it?

Comment: can you try with the mail / mailx / email or similar commands to see if  you can send mail with them? that way you'll know if the problem is in your code or elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Email::Send is now deprecated. This works for me, using the preferred Email::Sender:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();

my $smtpserver = 'server';
my $smtpport = 587;
my $smtpuser   = 'username';
my $smtppassword = 'password';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS->new({
  host => $smtpserver,
  port => $smtpport,
  ssl => "starttls",
  sasl_username => $smtpuser,
  sasl_password => $smtppassword,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'mymail@gmail.com',
    From    => 'sender@example.com',
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  body => "This is my message\n",
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

Comment: I think we need a big "deprecated, use xxx instead" message on cpan.

Answer (score 1):

Both modules you chose are not working unfortunately, you should use [Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aTLS%3a%3aButMaintained) instead of Net::SMTP::TLS and [Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSend%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aGmail) instead of Email::Send::Gmail. The modules you chose are old and unmaintained and known to be broken.

Sometimes it helps to check the bug reports available via the module's CPAN pages.

Comment: I think we need a big "deprecated, use xxx instead" message on cpan.